# Shell doesn't respond first input character after executing my program which executes shell command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, keyboard, xterm

I had a C program which is trying to do remote command execution using (rsh) command. It is trying to pull IP information and executed command. After executing my program, I was landed in shell prompt. My C program successfully existed (Strace and ps -ef confirmed the same).

When a type any character in a shell now, shell doesn't respond. It works well for next key typing.

I am using bash shell

C program looks something like this.

```
char *cmdline = "/sbin/ip link show bond0 2>/dev/null && inf=bond0 || inf=eth0;"
                                                        "/sbin/ip -6 addr show $inf scope link | /bin/awk '/inet6/ { print \$2 }'";
                        char *getpeerip = "/usr/bin/rsh $(/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | /bin/awk '/inet/ { print \$2 }'"
                                                        "| /bin/awk -F: '{ print \$2 }'"
                                                        "| /bin/awk -F. '{ printf \"%%s.%%s.%%s.%d\", \$1, \$2, \$3 }') "
                                                        "\"/sbin/ip link show bond0 2>/dev/null && inf=bond0 || inf=eth0;"
                                                        "/sbin/ip -6 addr show $inf scope link | /bin/awk '/inet6/ { print \\$2 }'\"";
                        char lnkbuf[300];

                        cpid = p_getset->local_addr_ids[i].entity_instance;
                        if (cpid == getThisCPNum()) {
                                cmd_file = popen(cmdline, "r");
                        } else {
                                sprintf(lnkbuf, getpeerip, 1+getPeerCPSlot());
                                cmd_file = popen(lnkbuf, "r");
                        }
                        if (cmd_file != NULL) {
                                fgets(lnkbuf, 100, cmd_file);
                                fclose(cmd_file);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of "ip link show bond0" over rsh containing escape character causing console input problem.

I changed command like this. It worked.

char *cmdline = "/sbin/ip link show bond0 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && inf=bond0 || inf=eth0;"

I did the same thing for variable getpeerip.